# Cross server java scripting

Tags: javascript, webserver

I have an application running in websphere that invokes a new window which is loaded by weblogic server. When I close the child window which is running in weblogic server, I would like to refresh the parent window running in websphere.

I tried the following ways but all of them were throwing permission denied script error.

```
window.opener.location.reload();
window.parent.functionName();
```

Please suggest a way to over come the cross server scripting error.

Answer (score 0):

i will assume that the 2 servers are hosted from/referenced via different domain names ie:

server1.com/ and server2.com/

Some browser functions are limited when called from a page with a different top level domain name.

you can use different sub-domains with the same top level domain though ie:

server1.server.com/
server2.server.com/

with this configuration browsers will let you do anything.

Comment: is there a way to achieve the same with out changing the domain name.

Comment: is there any setting that can be changed in web server or host entries of both domains

Answer (score 0):

I have not tired it out but previously I have seen that Cross domain calls were a problem with regular raw javascript. But was working pretty easily with JQuery APIs. Have a look in that direction.